# Can't download XML file

Tags: xml, curl, download, wget, cron-task

I'm trying to download XML file from the remote URL without success. I can see its content in the web browser, but can't download it through command line ( I can download it manually save as from the web browser ). I'm using wget:

```
wget -q -O test.xml https://example.com/test
```

I tried also using cURL without success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `-q` and you'll see:

> ```
> --2017-04-20 14:25:53--  https://example.com/test
> Resolving example.com... 93.184.216.34, 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
> Connecting to example.com|93.184.216.34|:443... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
> 2017-04-20 14:25:53 ERROR 404: Not Found.
> ```

The URL is a 404 error page. Consequently `text.xml` is empty.

Then if you look at the manual:

> ```
>    --content-on-error
>        If this is set to on, wget will not skip the content when the
>        server responds with a http status code that indicates error.
> ```

So:

```
wget -q --content-on-error -O test.xml https://example.com/test
```

… successfully downloads that resource.

It isn't valid XML though. The HTML 5 Doctype breaks it.

Comment: I'm getting:" failed: Connection timed out. Retrying". Very strange

Comment: @Blackcoat77 — That suggests it is a network problem between you and example.com. If it works in a browser: probably one related to proxy server configuration.

Comment: If I type wget -d https://example.com/test to view default HTTP request header, I'm getting:"Certificates loaded: 174" . If I replace above mentioned URL with google I'm getting proper HTTP request header.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that the problem can be related to proxy config

Answer (score 0):

Try set a header

```
wget -q -O --header="Accept:text/xml,*/*"  test.xml https://example.com/test
```